# SwiftUI two-way binding to value inside ObservableObject inside enum case

Tags: ios, swift, binding, swiftui, combine

I am trying to observe changes of a `bool` value contained in an `ObservableObject` which is a value in an `enum` case. Here is an example of what I am trying to achieve but with the current approach I receive the error `Use of unresolved identifier '$type1Value'`.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class ObservableType1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isChecked: Bool = false
}

enum CustomEnum {
    case option1(ObservableType1)
}

struct Parent: View {
    var myCustomEnum: CustomEnum
    var body: AnyView {
        switch myCustomEnum {
        case .option1(let type1Value):
            AnyView(Child(isChecked: $type1Value.isChecked)) // <- error here
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool
    var body: AnyView {
        AnyView(
            Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isChecked = !self.isChecked
        })
    }
}
```

I am trying to update the value of `isChecked` from the interface but since I want to have the `ObservableObject` which contains the property in an `enum` like `CustomEnum` not sure how to do it or if it is even possible. I went for an enum because there will be multiple enum options with different `ObservableObject` values and the `Parent` will generate different subviews depending on the `CustomEnum` option. If it makes any relevance the `Parent` will receive the `myCustomEnum` value from an `Array` of `CustomEnum` values. Is this even possible? If not, what alternatives do I have? Thank you!

Comment: The issue is that you only get the `$obj.prop` syntax for variables declared as `@ObservedObject` -- not on `ObservableObject`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, never say never... I've found interesting solution for this scenario, which even allows to remove AnyView. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4

Provided full testable module, just in case.

```
// just for test
struct Parent_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Parent(myCustomEnum: .option1(ObservableType1()))
    }
}

// no changes
class ObservableType1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isChecked: Bool = false
}

// no changes
enum CustomEnum {
    case option1(ObservableType1)
}

struct Parent: View {
    var myCustomEnum: CustomEnum

    var body: some View {
        self.processCases() // function to make switch work
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    private func processCases() -> some View {
        switch myCustomEnum {
        case .option1(let type1Value):
            ObservedHolder(value: type1Value) { object in
                Child(isChecked: object.isChecked)
            }
    }
}

// just remove AnyView
struct Child: View {
    @Binding var isChecked: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.isChecked = !self.isChecked
            }
    }
}
```

Here is a playmaker

```
struct ObservedHolder<T: ObservableObject, Content: View>: View {
    @ObservedObject var value: T
    var content: (ObservedObject<T>.Wrapper) -> Content

    var body: some View {
        content(_value.projectedValue)
    }
}
```

Comment: This really works, but if you have a second type like `.option2(let type2Value)` which has a value of `Child2` the return type still needs to be wrapped in `AnyView` but regardless, this works as intended. Thank you mlilions!

Answer (score -1):

This could work for your case:

```
import SwiftUI

class ObservableType1: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isChecked: Bool = false
}

enum CustomEnum {
    case option1(ObservableType1)
}

struct Parent: View {
    var myCustomEnum: CustomEnum
    var body: AnyView {
        switch (myCustomEnum) {
            case .option1:
                return AnyView(Child())
            default: return AnyView(Child())
        }
    }
}

struct Child: View {

    @ObservedObject var type1 = ObservableType1()

    var body: AnyView {
        AnyView(
            Image(systemName: self.type1.isChecked ? "checkmark.square" : "square")
            .onTapGesture {
                self.type1.isChecked.toggle()
        })
    }
}
```