# How to update view when value inside Enum changes with SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

Here is my code.
Run the MainView struct, and click on the button which *should* update the word `first` to the word `hello`.
It does not update at all even though the logs show that the data is correctly updated. Therefore is there no way to get the view to update when a value changes inside an enum?

The only way I got it to work was a nasty hack. To try the hack just uncomment the 3 lines of commented code and try it.  Is there a better way?

I looked at this similar question, but the same problem is there -> [SwiftUI two-way binding to value inside ObservableObject inside enum case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62029382/swiftui-two-way-binding-to-value-inside-observableobject-inside-enum-case)

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State var selectedEnum = AnEnum.anOption(AnObservedObject(string: "first"))
    // @State var update = false
    var body: some View {
        switch selectedEnum {
        case .anOption(var value):
            VStack {
                switch selectedEnum {
                case .anOption(let val):
                    Text(val.string)
                }
                TestView(object: Binding(get: { value }, set: { value = $0 }),
                         callbackToVerifyChange: callback)
            }
            // .id(update)
        }
    }
    
    func callback() {
        switch selectedEnum {
        case .anOption(let value):
            print("Callback function shows --> \(value.string)")
            // update.toggle()
        }
    }
}

class AnObservedObject: ObservableObject {
    @Published var string: String
    init(string: String) {
        self.string = string
    }
}

enum AnEnum {
    case anOption(AnObservedObject)
}

struct TestView: View {
    @Binding var object: AnObservedObject
    let callbackToVerifyChange: ()->Void
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tap here to change the word 'first' to 'hello'")
            .border(Color.black).padding()
            .onTapGesture {
                print("String before tapping --> \(object.string)")
                object.string = "hello"
                print("String after tapping --> \(object.string)")
                callbackToVerifyChange()
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really understand what do you try to achieve here... `selectedEnum` is not changed when you change property of reference-type AnObservedObject instance, because `anOption` contains same pointer.

Comment: The Value inside selected enum (the `string` of AnObservedObject) has changed. So I wanted the view to reflect the change?  There is a Text() view on the screen that contains the value inside the enum. And although that value has changed, the TextView still contains the same old string value -> `first`.   The screen is not updated at all.  So i needed any help on this...

Comment: I can get it to work however, if i uncomment the hack shown above.  As a side note, the reasoning why I have the objects inside enums is so i have have different object types and create different view based on them. The other alternative is having an array of `Any` which I do not like so much.

Comment: @Asperi If i am still unclear.. then let me know. I will try to get a better work around, because the hack kills all animation because the view is forced to redraw itself.

Comment: The simple answer is that a value type (`struct`, `enum`) that has a reference-type property isn't being mutated when a property of that reference-type property is changed, because that property - being a reference - hasn't changed - it still points to the same thing. So, `@State var selectedEnum` doesn't observe a change, and doesn't recompute the view

Comment: @NewDev ok. I understand why it is happening. I guess I asked the question if someone has some way to make values inside an enum work this way? Or If I had to do it, whats the best way to approach this?

Comment: @Justacoder, not really. That's how Swift value-types work. You'd need to assign `selectedEnum` a new value, even if it's the same case, to get it to "change"

Comment: Instead of forcing a state change by changing another state property with `update.toggle()`, you could just add a mutating function to `AnEnum`, e.g. `extension AnEnum { mutating func update() {} }` and call that. But the main issue is why is `AnObservedObject` a `class` to begin with? This wouldn't have been a problem if it was a `struct`

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your enum `Equatable`.